# Modyfing higher order functions output in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, higher-order-functions

I want to create helper function that modifies output returned by higher-order function.

Example of higher-order function:

```clj
(def use-meta-sub (make-app-fn (make-sub :meta)))
```

The problem is that when using this in let like this:

```clj
(let [meta-sub (use-meta-sub props :get-me-meta-of-this)])
```

returns map of key-value pairs like this:

```clj
{:key-we-almost-never-need-1 nil
 :key-we-almost-never-need-2 nil
 :key-we-almost-never-need-3 nil
 :key-we-almost-never-need-4 nil
 :meta-data {:something-useful "foo"
             :more-usefull      "bar"
             :and-so-on         "baz"}}
```

I would like to target only this `:meta-data` key

I tried this and some other variations:

```clj
(defn use-meta-data-sub [props ctrl]
  (:meta-data (use-meta-sub props ctrl))) ;; both with get
```

It does not work because (I think, that returns lazy sequence and I do not know how to actually firs evaluate it and then extract the key from output).

Is this possible without editing 1st higher-order function, and other two it contains?

(I read all documentation on clojure site and clojure-unraveled, either I do not understand them, or they do not cover this)

Comment: I think you want `(let [meta-sub (use-meta-sub props :get-me-meta-of-this)] (:meta-data meta-sub))` (or maybe `select-keys`) - other than that, you would have to change the function to return you something different. Without sharing the code, there is nearly no way to help here.

Comment: "(I read all documentation on clojure site and clojure-unraveled, either I do not understand them, or they do not cover this)" It's covered. See `comp`.